# Behat could not load mock class already exists

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking, behat, gherkin

I am trying to mock a class in Laravel using the following. However, I get the following error. Any ideas?

> Could not load mock \App\Repositories\FetchDataEndpoints\Test, class
> already exists.

```
\Mockery::mock('overload:\App\Repositories\FetchDataEndpoints\Test')
    ->shouldReceive([
        'getPaymentStatus' => 'test'
]);
```

Comment: There is a solution for this, but why are you not doing a traditional mock? can i see the code where getPaymentStatus is called and how you are instantiating FetchDataEndpoints\Test